# int型の値を文字列として連結したい

Tags: java

`a + b` の値は `int` 型です。　`a = 1`, `b = 2`です。　
`String.valueOf()` で `String` 型に変更して `a + b` を12と表示させたいです。
しかし、以下のように試したコードではうまくいきませんでした。

- `return String.valueOf(a + b)`　→　4となってしまう。
- `return String.valueOf("a "+ "b")`　→　abとなってしまう。

どうしたら12を表示させられるか教えていただきたいです。

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`String.valueOf()` は利用していませんが、`int`型を連結するのであれば次も利用可能です:

```
int a = 1;
int b = 2;
String str = "" + a + b;
System.out.println(str);
```

参考:

- [How to concatenate int values in java?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2674750/4506703) - Stack Overflow

---

仕様は次のリンクの通りになります。

- [15.18.1. String Concatenation Operator +](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se11/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.18.1)

簡単に言うと、 `x + y` の `x`か`y`の一方が`String`の場合、`+`は特別な挙動となり、他方を文字列変換した上で、両者文字列の連結になります。

`a + b` だと単に `int` 同士の計算ですが、最初に `"" + a` とすることで`String`と`int`の計算、つまり上記の仕様にある条件に当てはまるようになります。
ですので、空文字列と`a`を文字列化したものの連結、つまり `a`を文字列化したものが得られます。

更に `上で計算した結果 + b`の計算を行うわけですが、これも`String`と`int`の計算になります。

そういうわけで、最終的に得られるのは`aを文字列化したもの`と`bを文字列化したもの`を連結した文字列になります。

Comment: ありがとうございます！え、abはint型なのに、型変換していないのにString str = "" + a + b;このような式は可能なんでしょうか？

Comment: 必ず型変換としか代入はできないと習ったのですが、、かならずしもそうでない。。String str = "" + a + b;　の””のところがよくわからないです。。

Answer (score 3):

単純にそれっぽい式を組み合わせてみただけ、のように見えます。どのような順序で処理を行えば良いのか、しっかり考えられるようにして下さい。

- `int`型同士の`+`演算は、数値としての計算を行う。(`1 + 2`は整数値の`3`になる。)
- `String`型同士の`+`演算は、文字列としての連結を行う。(`"1" + "2"`は文字列の"12"になる。)

あなたは後者の「文字列としての連結」を行いたいのですから、`String`型の`"1"`と`"2"`を`+`演算の前に作っておく、と言う必要があります。

ご質問内の書き方に合わせて1つの式で表すと、

```
        return String.valueOf(a) + String.valueOf(b);
```

とでもなるでしょう。

Comment: 実行できました。ありがとうございます！
return String.valueOf(a) + String.valueOf(b);　→　このような書き方ができるとは知りませんでした。必ず String.valueOf()は１つしかかけないと思っておりました。

Comment: @iuy さん、コメントありがとうございます。`String.valueOf()`のような式は別の式の一部としても使えます。いまはまだボンヤリとしか全貌が掴めていないかもしれませんが、そう言った書き方もできると言うのをどんどん経験していくと自然にわかるようになってくると思います。わからないことがあるうちは、質問をうまくまとめるのも大変かもしれませんが、一つずつ解決していくようにしてください。

Comment: 教えて頂きありがとうございます！このような書き方は見たことないし、できないだろうなという思い込みはまず捨てないといけないなと思いました！ありがとうございます！